# BIRT csv emitter and EJB

Tags: birt

I want to use csv emitter plugin in a Java EE application. Is it possible? I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.UnsupportedFormatException: The output format csv is not supported.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.setupRenderOption(EngineTask.java:2047)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:96)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
```

My code:

```
protected String generateReportFile(IRunAndRenderTask task, IReportRunnable design, IReportEngine engine, String reportType, String reportPrefix, String baseDir) throws BirtReportGenerationFault {
      CSVRenderOption csvOptions = new CSVRenderOption();

        csvOptions.setOutputFormat(CSVRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_CSV);

        csvOptions.setOutputFileName("C:/birt/logs/csvTestW.csv");

        csvOptions.setShowDatatypeInSecondRow(false);

        csvOptions.setExportTableByName("data");

        csvOptions.setDelimiter("\t");

        csvOptions.setReplaceDelimiterInsideTextWith("-");

        task.setRenderOption(csvOptions);               
        task.setEmitterID("org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.csv");

        try {
            task.run();// Error here
        } catch (EngineException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        task.close();


    return "C:/birt/logs/csvTestW.csv";//fileName;
  }
```

Same code works in a Java SE app.

Comment: Do you have the csv emiter plug-in ? if you don't have download from here https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/csv-emitter-birt-plugin/downloads/list

Comment: Yes. Plugin is added to build path. As you can see in my code i am using org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.csv.CSVRenderOption class from this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with the pdf format. I solved it by adding org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.pdf to the plugin Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is case of output format passed to in CSVRenderOptions.

instead of using `csvOptions.setOutputFormat(CSVRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_CSV);`

 try using `csvOptions.setOutputFormat("CSV");`